# check results between two dates or null

Tags: mysql

I have no idea about how to search for rows between two dates and the case where the start date or end date are null.

**Here what I have done:**

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE ((start_date >= $start_date AND end_date <= $end_date) OR '$end_date'='' OR '$start_date'='')
```

But not a working example.

Comment: if they're null/empty, then don't run the query in the first place. You can trivially test `if ($end_date == '')` at the client code level. And note you're missing quotes on the `>=` tests. `2016-07-25` is not a date, it's a two-way subtraction operation and evalutes to the number `1984`. `'2016-07-25'` **IS** a date (note the quotes).

Comment: It's not a solution for me since other parameters will be included and need result with date or with no dates.

Comment: end_date <= '' will always be false when end_date is null.  '' is not NULL, '' is an empty string.  And NULL is not ''.  To test for NULL, use "is".  ... where $end_date is NULL

Comment: And the solution what is it ?

Answer (score -1):

This should be the right query
$query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE ((start_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date') OR start_date is NULL OR end_date is NULL)";
To check if some field is null or not null you should use syntax "field is NULL" or "field is not NULL"

Comment: False query, `OR start_date is NULL OR end_date is NULL` must be `OR $start_date is NULL OR $end_date is NULL` ... but even with this not work.

Comment: If you want to check if php variable is null or empty you have to check it in php and use different query in that case.

Comment: Want it from Mysqli

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE ((start_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date') OR '$start_date' = '' OR '$end_date' = '')"; - But if start or end date is empty the query will return all the rows from table.

Comment: But there is no change to my query in this case ! you didn't changed nothing to my posted query.